# How to create nested object and array in parquet file?

Tags: java, parquet

How do I create a parquet file with nested fields? I have the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int fileNum = 10;   //num of files constructed
    int fileRecordNum = 50; //record num of each file
    int rowKey = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNum; ++i) {

        Map<String, String> metas = new HashMap<>();
        metas.put(HConstants.START_KEY, genRowKey("%10d", rowKey + 1));
        metas.put(HConstants.END_KEY, genRowKey("%10d", rowKey + fileRecordNum));

        ParquetWriter<Group> writer = initWriter("pfile/scanner_test_file" + i, metas);

        for (int j = 0; j < fileRecordNum; ++j) {
            rowKey++;
            Group group = sfg.newGroup().append("rowkey", genRowKey("%10d", rowKey))
                    .append("cf:name", "wangxiaoyi" + rowKey)
                    .append("cf:age", String.format("%10d", rowKey))
                    .append("cf:job", "student")
                    .append("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
            writer.write(group);
        }

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I want to create two fields:

1. Hobbies which contains a list of hobbies ("Swimming", "Kickboxing")
2. A teacher object that contains subfields like:
   {
   'teachername': 'Rachel',
   'teacherage':50
   }

Can someone provide an example how to do this in Java?

Comment: Where is the data source you'd like to create those objects from? Are you simply asking how to create a list of strings and an object to populate from some sort of input, but in `java`?

Comment: I too have a hard time understanding what exactly you are asking for. Too a certain degree, that looks like some almost-json like data format that you want  to create?

Answer (score -7):

Parquet is *columned* (mini-storages) key-value storage... I.e. this kind of storage cannot keep nested data, but this storage accepts converting *logical* types of data to binary format (byte array with header that contains data to understand what kind of convertation should be applied to this data).

I'm not sure about how should you implement your converter, but basically you should work with [`Binary`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/io/api/Binary.java) class as data container and create some converter... sample converter you can find for `String` data type.

Comment: Parquet definitely supports nested structures (http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/) *Parquet is built from the ground up with complex nested data structures in mind*.

Comment: Parquet supports "repetition level" and "definition level" to handle complex data structure and arrays.